# Using eval on a function string

Tags: javascript

I am doing :

```
eval('function(){ console.log("Hello World"); }')();
```

But that gives error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Worksforme in Opera's console. How do you test it, in which environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eval` operator expects a *Program* as input, and the grammar of JavaScript requires that all
top-level program elements are either declarations or statements.

The [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.1) says:

> Let prog be the ECMAScript code that is the result of parsing x as a Program.

`function` can't start a top-level statement, but it can start a function declaration, but only when it has a name.

That's why you get "Unexpected token ("; it expects a function name before the parenthesis that opens the argument list.

As others have noted, to `eval` a function, you need to trick the JavaScript parser into finding an expression where it expects a statement.  Wrapping the body in parentheses is one way to do this.

Comment: Not if you're passing a self-invoking function, which I believe is what he is attempting to do (due to his dubious added parenthesis on the end of the `eval` method)

Comment: @shennan, I'm not sure I understand.  `eval` does what it does.  The string the OP is passing in is a valid function expression, but is not a valid expression statement.

Comment: I agree with you. What I'm saying is, his added parenthesis at the end of his `eval` method (please take another look at it), is indication that perhaps he was attempting an anonymous function call, but misconstrued as to where the required extra parenthesis should be.

Comment: @shennan, I think we agree.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:

```
eval( '(function(){ console.log("Hello World"); })()' );
```

Let's break it down. You have a self invoking function (a function that calls itself):

```
(function(){ console.log("Hello World"); })()
```

And you're passing it as a string argument to the `eval` method:

```
eval( '(function(){ console.log("Hello World"); })()' );
```

Your main error is trying to *call* what `eval` returns by adding parenthesis on the end of the `eval` method call. If you want the function your passing to immediately invoke itself, the added parenthesis should be part of the thing your passing to `eval`.

I'm assuming you're trying to do something other than call "Hello World", as you could simply do this:

```
eval( 'console.log("Hello World");' );
```

Or, dare I say:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` expects a statement but:

- `function(){}` is not valid as a statement because the function name is missing.
- `(function(){})` is instead recognized because the statement is a "statement expression".

The problem is that `function` as first token triggers the function declaration rule when a statement is expected. When an expression is expected instead (e.g. inside parenthesis) then `function` triggers the function expression rules where a name is optional but not mandatory.